# Using pre-compiled frameworks

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I want my Xcode project to point to pre compiled frameworks,

I have a folder in my home directory called preCompiled

inside their are folders such as FolderA which contains folders of different versions such as 2.0, 3.0

inside of the version folders there is an xc framework

how would I add these paths along with an xconfig that determines which version it should choose to use at build time.

Folder Structure:
$(HOME)/preCompiled/FolderA/{version_number}/FolderA.xcframework

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the framework in the General Tab from the Project Settings?

[image: Frameworks section]

Just press the "+" button at the bottom!
Then try this:

[image: Add other dependency]

I believe Add Files is the right selection.